# Image list is not aligned in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

I have a list of different images each with a unique link. In Chrome only, the 5th item of the list drops and is not aligned with the preceding images. The relevant code is here: http://jsfiddle.net/leewhite/z4c2S/

It works fine in other browsers. Any help much appreciated!

The HTML is:

```
<div id="acontent">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#" class="a1">1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="a2">2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="a3">3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="a4">4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="a5">5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="a6">6</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="a7">7</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="a8">8</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="a9">9</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="a10">10</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And the CSS is:

```
#acontent {
    position:relative;
    display:block;
    float:left;
    width:370px;
    height:200px;
    margin-left:10px;
}
#acontent ul {
    list-style:none;
    display:inline;
}
#acontent li {
    list-style:none;
    display:inline;
}
#acontent a.a1 {
    width:74px;
    height:100px;
    float:left;
    background-color:#F00000
}
#acontent a.a2 {
    width:74px;
    height:100px;
    float:left;
    background-color:#FA0000
}
#acontent a.a3 {
    width:74px;
    height:100px;
    float:left;
    background-color:#AF0000
}
#acontent a.a4 {
    width:74px;
    height:100px;
    float:left;
    background-color:#BF0000
}
#acontent a.a5 {
    width:74px;
    height:100px;
    float:left;
    background-color:#FF0005
}
#acontent a.a6 {
    width:74px;
    height:100px;
    float:left;
    background-color:#CA0000
}
#acontent a.a7 {
    width:74px;
    height:100px;
    float:left;
    background-color:#DA0000
}
#acontent a.a8 {
    width:74px;
    height:100px;
    float:left;
    background-color:#EE0000
}
#acontent a.a9 {
    width:74px;
    height:100px;
    float:left;
    background-color:#A30000
}
#acontent a.a10 {
    width:74px;
    height:100px;
    float:left;
    background-color:#B70000
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the containing "ul" display set to "inline" so it is appearing as an inline element and pushing the last list item down. if you change #acontent ul to the following it'll fix your issue. See also this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Lv4rz/3/

```
#acontent ul {
   list-style:none;
   display:block;
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
}
```

UPDATE: The issue isn't actually the display type, the issue is the "ul" originally had margin and padding. You don't need to set display:block, to fix your issue. You only really need to set the margin and padding to zero.